# Single page With React Router V6

Tags: reactjs

Hello I am trying to make a react single page using the react router v 6, but I have the following error:

TypeError
Cannot read property 'location' of undefined

and I'm also not able to imagine the logic of how to do this basically I just want to change my ContentOne to ContentTwo

**code:**

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <route />
    </Router>
  );
}
```

**Routes:**

```
export default function MainRoutes() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <MainWrapper>
        <Route path="/" element={<Header />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<ContentOne />} />
        <Route path="/contenttwo" element={<ContentTwo />} />
        <Route path="/" element={<Footer />} />
      </MainWrapper>
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

**Header:**

```
const Render = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  return (
    <Header>
      <button onClick={() => history.push("/")}>ContentOne</button>
      <button onClick={() => history.push("/contenttwo")}>ContentTwo</button>
    </Header>
  );
};

export default Render;
```

**contentOne:**

```
const Render = () => {
  return <ContentOne />;
};

export default Render;
```

**contentTwo:**

```
const Render = () => {
  return <ContentTwo />;
};

export default Render;
```

**Footer:**

```
const Render = () => {
  return <Footer />;
};

export default Render;
```

example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-paper-ps1vw

Comment: Can you clarify why you are using buttons for navigation instead Link component from react router? Also why are you using prop element instead of component for Route components? Did you have a chance to review the documentation and provided example? https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Comment: yes: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/releases/tag/v6.0.0-alpha.2 i use react router v6.

Comment: basically i'm trying to make a single page application, just changing the content from one to two when clicking the button.

Comment: Okay I stand corrected about element prop, but what about trying to use Link instead of button? Also link would resolve to an anchor would be more semantically correct no matter what.

Comment: I thought about how to button I don't know the best option I am new with react router gift I am trying to understand but I am having difficulties even I had used this in another project and it had worked (from the button)

Comment: Your example needs to first be fixed please. It's using `react-router-dom` version `5.1.2`. Unfortunately nothing from the v6 guide will really work with v5. Would need to have the equivalent of `npm install history@5 react-router@6 react-router-dom@6` for this to work or to troubleshoot farther. Any reason you are using an alpha version of this library?

Comment: No no,  i joined git and got the most current version, could you help me how can i do the single page with version 5?